# ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

Okay. So I downloaded java 12.0.1 and I have set my `JAVA_HOME` and `path` variables to my jdk bin loaction. In CMD, when I run `java -version`, it does work, and I get the version. Everything works fine.

## Problem:

However, in the libGDX setup (gdx-setup.jar) when I try to **Generate Code**, I get this following error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk- 
12.0.1\bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

However, any other app that uses `Java` works (such as **Eclipse IDE**).

What am I doing wrong? Does libGDX not support `java 12.0.1`?

Comment: JAVA_HOME doesn't usually include the bin folder. It usually just points to the folder of the jre or jdk. So in your case, I'd try to set `JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk- 
12.0.1 `.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this gaming framework libGDX best supports java 7(jkd 1.7). Refer below the links. You can install Jdk 7 or 8 and you can try.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4619

https://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=25857

Comment: I cannot install JDK 7 beacuse it is not supported anymore by oracle, and JDK give me Error Code 13 when I start ecplise.

Comment: You can install, Oracle says they do not support from an enterprise installation view point. But for development, you can install. Go to Oracle archive site and you can download.

Comment: LibGDX supports Java 12 without any problem, this is wrong.

Comment: @Nicolas, I never said it supports or not, I provided some useful links to the user so that he can try. You made wrong inference.

Comment: @Nicolas JDK 12 does not work in libGDX, have you even read my question?

Comment: @CodingM I'm using JDK 11 and it works fine, it shouldn't be any different with JDK 12, since java is (mostly) backward compatible. In any case, as tronski pointed out, your java home is wrong, which is likely the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Nicolas Ive tried a lot of things. I will try JDK 11, with what is suggested.

Comment: @Nicolas Currently I have JDK 8 installed and the path correctly set. For some reason, this ONE time it worked. Pretty surprised as ive tried jdk 8 already. Thanks?